# matlab: apply an operand on an array by a condition

Tags: matlab

I have an array like this:

```
>> a = [2,34,5,6,7,0,1,10]
```

now I want to reverse each element of this array.
By using `1 ./ a` the result is:

```
ans =

0.5000    0.0294    0.2000    0.1667    0.1429       Inf    1.0000    0.1000
```

The `Inf` is not good for me, the answer should be

```
ans =

0.5000    0.0294    0.2000    0.1667    0.1429       0    1.0000    0.1000
```

I want to apply this on elements that are not zero!

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also reset the `Inf` value to zero afterwards:

```
>> b=1./a

b =

0.5000    0.0294    0.2000    0.1667    0.1429       Inf    1.0000    0.1000

>> b(isinf(b)) = 0

b =

0.5000    0.0294    0.2000    0.1667    0.1429         0    1.0000    0.1000
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it conditionally:

```
nz = a ~= 0; %// select using logical indexing
a(nz) = 1./a(nz);
```

Comment: This seems reasonable for this case but can be challenging for more complex functions.

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia in what way? `a(nz) = complexFunction( a(nz) );` - is simple enough...

Comment: I meant in finding where `complexFunction == +/-Inf` happens. Here it is easy to see `nz = a ~= 0` returns the indices of `Inf` in `b` but what if `b=1./(sin(a.^2) - sin(a.^3+log(a)))`. How do you find `nz`?

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia you have a point. On the other hand, if `complexFunction` is indeed complex, it might be best not to evaluate it on all elements to begin with, assuming you defined the complex function and know for which values it is well defined...

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia what if `complemFunciton` returns `inf`s *and* `NaN`s? please see my other answer. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: I think you have to ask the OP. `NaN` is not mentioned in the question but should be considered in most cases. The interpretation might be different though. `Inf` usually shows you have a divergence somewhere, but `NaN` shows there is no unique limit. `log(0)` and `1/0` are meaningful divergent cases but `0/0` can have different meanings depending on the context.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more general approach than [m.s.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30595428/1714410)'s is to check for *finite* elements in the output using [`isfinite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isfinite.html):

```
b = 1./a;
b( ~isfinite(b) ) = 0;
```

[`isfinite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isfinite.html) covers **both** `inf` values as well as `NaN` values, so if the element-wise function you are applying might generate both types of non-numeric values, [`isfinite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isfinite.html) handles them simultaneously for you.